# ¿Como pasar un string a una función onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

En mi `html` tengo  un atributo `onClick` y dentro de el una `función()` la cual le estoy pasando dos parametros, un entero y un string..

**HTML**

```
<span onClick="dataUser(3,admin);" style="cursor: pointer">Ver Usuario</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
function dataUser(p1,p2){
 console.log(p2);
}
```

y la consola me arroja:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: admin is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

¿A que se debe este error? ¿La función no recibe string's?

Comment: Si quieres pasar el string `'admin'` debes encerrarlo entre comillas: `onclick="datauser(3, 'admin');"`

Comment: Recomiendo el uso de [JS no obstrusivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_no_obstructivo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías enviar el parámetro admin entre ''. Te tendría que quedar de la siguiente manera:

```js
function dataUser(numero, string) {
  console.log(numero, string);
}
```

```html
<span onClick="dataUser(3,'admin');" style="cursor: pointer">Ver Usuario</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si `admin` es un texto debería ir entre comillas.

Comment: Simples, por que si lo hace con dobles, generará error de etiquetado de html.

Comment: No iban por ahí los tiros, pero bien comentado.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, me ha funcionado.

Comment: @JDavid si la respuesta te ha servido (esta o cualquier otra), podes aceptarla por favor?

Answer (score 2):

Colócale comillas simples:

```js
function dataUser(a,b){
  console.log(a + b)
}
```

```html
<span onClick="dataUser(3,'admin');" style="cursor: pointer">Ver Usuario</span>
```